# android studio error : org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, compiler-errors

I couldn't sync and build my project.i have this error and I upgrade everything that I need.
I don't make change on my project and when I use the default settings this error appears in my project.
it is a blank activity page and I can't build any kind of project.
how can I fix it?

**Screenshot of the error:**

[image]

**The error:**

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidApis'.
Failed to transform file 'android.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-mockable-jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime-jars, returnDefaultValues=false}
Execution failed for MockableJarTransform: C:\Users\amirb\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar.
org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor
org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor
```